# How to loop json data in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON data from server end but it is not as I wanted. My json data have several loop which I want to convert into single one.

**JSON I am getting**

```
    [
  [
    "Year",
    "2018-9",
    "2017-9"
  ],
  [
    "JAYANAGAR",
    "2018-9",
    857
  ],
  [
    "MALLESHWARAM",
    "2018-9",
    169
  ],
  [
    "KOLAR",
    "2018-9",
    178
  ],
  [
    "JAYANAGAR",
    "2017-9",
    635
  ],
  [
    "MALLESHWARAM",
    "2017-9",
    56
  ],
  [
    "KOLAR",
    "2017-9",
    90
  ]
]
```

Here the outlets i.e jayanagar malleshwaram and kolar are repeating with the different dates I have

I am trying to convert it into something like this

```
 [
  [
    "Year",
    "2018-9",
    "2017-9"
  ],
  [
    "Jayanagar",
    857,
    635
  ],
  [
    "Malleshwaram",
    169,
    56
  ],
  [
    "Kolar",
    178,
    90
  ]
]
```

In my first json data is repeating with date which are `2018-8` and `2017-8`

I want to map the data and reduce it into like I am trying to get.

I know it can be done with JavaScript but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your data for each "place" is in the correct order of year, you could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) like this:

```js
const input=[["Year","2018-9","2017-9"],["JAYANAGAR","2018-9",857],["MALLESHWARAM","2018-9",169],["KOLAR","2018-9",178],["JAYANAGAR","2017-9",635],["MALLESHWARAM","2017-9",56],["KOLAR","2017-9",90]]

const merged = input.reduce((acc, arr) => {
  const [city, year, value] = arr;
  
  if (city === "Year")
    acc[city] = arr
  else {
    acc[city] = acc[city] || [city]
    acc[city].push(value)
  }
  
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Object.values(merged)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can group the data to create the desired structure

```js
const first = foo.shift();
const res = Array.from(
  foo.reduce((a, [t,_,n]) => a.set(t, (a.get(t) || []).concat(n)), new Map)
).map(e => [].concat(...e));
res.unshift(first);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const foo = [
  [
    'Year',
    '2018-9',
    '2017-9'
  ],
  [
    'JAYANAGAR',
    '2018-9',
    857
  ],
  [
    'MALLESHWARAM',
    '2018-9',
    169
  ],
  [
    'KOLAR',
    '2018-9',
    178
  ],
  [
    'JAYANAGAR',
    '2017-9',
    635
  ],
  [
    'MALLESHWARAM',
    '2017-9',
    56
  ],
  [
    'KOLAR',
    '2017-9',
    90
  ]
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataSet = [
  [
    "Year",
    "2018-9",
    "2017-9"
  ],
  [
    "JAYANAGAR",
    "2018-9",
    857
  ],
  [
    "MALLESHWARAM",
    "2018-9",
    169
  ],
  [
    "KOLAR",
    "2018-9",
    178
  ],
  [
    "JAYANAGAR",
    "2017-9",
    635
  ],
  [
    "MALLESHWARAM",
    "2017-9",
    56
  ],
  [
    "KOLAR",
    "2017-9",
    90
  ]
];

const dataBody = dataSet.slice(1);
const transformedDataBody = dataBody.reduce(function (currentValue, nextValue){
    currentValue[nextValue[0]] = currentValue[nextValue[0]] || [nextValue[0]];
    currentValue[nextValue[0]].push(nextValue[2]);
    return currentValue; 
}, {})
let finalDataSet = [ dataSet[0] ];
Object.keys(transformedDataBody).map(function(key){
 finalDataSet.push(transformedDataBody[key]);
})
console.log(finalDataSet);
```

This is what you want?